# How to combine several Qt UI project in one project and compile it to a library?

Tags: qt4, npapi

As title. I am using Qt4.

How to combine several Qt UI project in one project and compile it to a library??

I compile it and use the library into my npapi plugin.

My plugin will crash ><

Does anyone give me some help?

Comment: Have you checked to see why it is crashing? attached a debugger, caught the crash, seen what is going on? That might help you figure out what is happening

Comment: Thanks for your respond.
It always crashed at ui.show(). Before combining the several project, every project works fine in each project. After combining these project, it crashed at show() function.

Comment: that's great, but what is crashing? what is the exception or message?